# how to solve this problem in angular?and let me know how to install bootstrap@15.1.1

Tags: angular-bootstrap

```
The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@15.1.1 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: blog@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@16.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.2.8" from @angular/animations@16.2.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"16.2.8" from @angular/platform-browser@16.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"16.2.8" from @angular/forms@16.2.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@"^16.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@11.0.2
npm ERR!         node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^16.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@11.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm ERR!       ngx-bootstrap@"^11.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.2.8" from @angular/common@16.2.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"16.2.8" from @angular/forms@16.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"^16.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@11.0.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm ERR!         ngx-bootstrap@"^11.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"16.2.8" from @angular/platform-browser@16.2.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"16.2.8" from @angular/forms@16.2.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@"^16.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@11.0.2
npm ERR!         node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     4 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR!   7 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"15.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@16.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"16.2.9" from @angular/forms@16.2.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^16.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^16.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@15.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"15.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-16T08_34_08_305Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-16T08_34_08_305Z-debug-0.log
× Packages installation failed, see above.
```

i try to install bootstrap in angular . in that The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@15.1.1 was already in it cant be work showing some error